# как остановить анимацию ProgressBar indeterminate

Tags: java, android

как остановить анимацию ProgressBar(Normal) indeterminate ?

чтобы остановить анимацию пишу такой код, но не работает

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.clearAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1):

Анимацию в indeterminate ProgressBar остановить невозможно. Она для этого не предназначена абсолютно. Если хотите иметь возможность делать что-то подобное, вам придется написать свой собственный прогрессбар.
Но что-то мне подсказывает, что ваша проблема решается менее извращенным способом. Опишите, зачем вам это надо?